# Login with twitter using identity server is not working when using openidconnect

Tags: asp.net-core, twitter, identityserver4, twitter-oauth

I'm attempting to integrate Twitter login functionality into my application using Identity Server. I've utilized AddOpenIdConnect for this purpose. Below is the code snippet I've employed:

```
authenticationBuilder
    .AddOpenIdConnect(Configuration.GetSection("ExternalLoginConfiguration:TwitterConfiguration:Scheme").Value, "twitter", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = "Identity.External";
        options.ClientId = Configuration.GetSection("ExternalLoginConfiguration:TwitterConfiguration:ClientId").Value;
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration.GetSection("ExternalLoginConfiguration:TwitterConfiguration:ClientSecret").Value;
        options.CallbackPath = "/signin-twitter";
        options.Authority = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize";
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;                   
        options.SaveTokens = true;
    });
```

However, I'm encountering an issue, which is

> {   "StatusCode":500,   "Message":"IDX20803: Unable to obtain
> configuration from:
> 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize/.well-known/openid-configuration'.,The
> server encountered an internal error, for more information please
> check the server error logs." }

Upon using AddTwitter, the login process is successful. However, I encounter difficulties in accurately retrieving access tokens.

Comment: You could try the specific Twitter package instead of AddOpenIDConnect https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter/9.0.0-preview.2.24128.4 , it is tweaked to better support Twitter.